# Hive - Select unique rows based on some key field

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using `Hive 1.2.1` and want to select unique rows based on empid

```
empid  empname  dept 
101    aaaa     dept1
101    aaaa     dept2
102    bbbb     dept1
103    cccc     dept2
```

I tried to use correlated subquery but that does not work

```
select empid, 
       empname,
    dept
       (select count(*) 
        from emp t2 
        where t2.empid = t1.empid) as row_number
from emp t1 where row_number=1
order by empid;
```

Is there a way to select unique value based on some key field? Need your help..

Expected output would be

```
empid  empname  dept 
101    aaaa     dept1
102    bbbb     dept1
103    cccc     dept2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: I edited my question, added expected output.

Comment: one of the probable solution would be `select empid, max(empname) as empname1, max(dept) as dept1 from emp group by empid;`. My actual table has large number of columns and don't want to use above sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a single row per unique key, than you can use row_number():

```
select empid, empname, dept from (
select row_number() over (partition by empid order by empname , dept) as rowNum, empid, empname, dept from table
) q where rowNum == 1
```

Comment: Thanks... From which version Hive started supported partition by? Do you have any link for this?

Comment: Written query from memory, update the answer. Looks like since Hive 0.11, the only link I found is https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics